Can I help myself with this Doctor Flutter error?
enter image description here
Can someone help me solve this problem, when I run 'DoctorFlutter' in the Windows cmd, this first error appears that has to do with VS code, can you help me solve it, I saw a similar question but it was from MacOs, can someone tell me how to do it? do I solve for windows?

take a look on this answer

Did you installed dart separately in your macOS?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Welcome to stackoverflow. In general, it is preferable to include error messages as a text instead of an image. The title of your post should summarize the specific problem. I recommend having a look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
